# Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building a android application with c++ code support. When I try to build the application I get the following error

```
    Error:'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    make: *** [clean-ObjectRecognition-armeabi] Error 1

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
    > Build command failed.
    Error while executing 'E:\Android\AndroidSDK\SDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib clean}
    Android NDK: WARNING:E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk:ObjectRecognition: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
    Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
    Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
    Android NDK:     current module    
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    make: *** [clean-ObjectRecognition-armeabi] Error 1


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This is my Android.mk file contents
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include E:/Android/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-    sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := ObjectRecognition
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ObjectRecognition.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have placed the ObjectRecognition.cpp along with androidmk inside app-> src-> main-> jni

What would i need to do to fix this error.

**EDIT 1:**
I ran this command in the terminal

```
E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition>ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null     APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\build\intermediate\ndkBuild\debug\lib clean NDK_LOG=1
```

I got this output

```
    Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: 'E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//..'
    Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
    Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: windows
    Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: windows
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
    Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to windows
    Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
    Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe -n
    Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/cmp.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'awk' test returned: Pass
    Android NDK: Found platform root directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms
    Android NDK: Found supported platforms: android-12 android-13 android-14 android-15 android-16 android-17 android-18 android-19 android-21 android-22 android-23 android-2
    4 android-9
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-12 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-13 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-14 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-15 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-16 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-17 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-18 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-19 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-21 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-22 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-23 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-24 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-9 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-x86
    Android NDK: Found stable platform levels: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 9
    Android NDK: Found max platform level: 24
    Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following target architectures and ABIS:
    Android NDK:    arm: armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    arm64: arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    mips: mips
    Android NDK:    mips64: mips64
    Android NDK:    x86: x86
    Android NDK:    x86_64: x86_64
    Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following toolchains and target ABIs:
    Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-4.9:  arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-clang:  arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.9:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-4.9:  mips64
    Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-clang:  mips64
    Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.9:  mips
    Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang:  mips
    Android NDK:    x86-4.9:  x86
    Android NDK:    x86-clang:  x86
    Android NDK:    x86_64-4.9:  x86_64
    Android NDK:    x86_64-clang:  x86_64
    Android NDK: Make no attempt to look for NDK_PROJECT_PATH.
    Android NDK: Ouput path for intermediate files: E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
    Android NDK: Ouput path for generated library files: E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib
    Android NDK: Parsing E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk
    Android NDK:   APP_PIE is
    Android NDK:   Enabling -fPIE
    Android NDK:   Using build script E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
    Android NDK: Application 'local' is not debuggable
    Android NDK: Selecting release optimization mode (app is not debuggable)
    Android NDK: Adding import directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources
    Android NDK: Building application 'local' for ABI 'armeabi'
    Android NDK:   Enabling -fPIE for TARGET_PLATFORM android-19
    Android NDK: Using target toolchain 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang' for 'armeabi' ABI (through NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)
    Android NDK: Looking for imported module with tag 'cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++'
    Android NDK:   Probing E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk
    Android NDK:     Found in E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++
    Android NDK: Module 'ObjectRecognition' has C++ sources
    Android NDK: Add dependency 'gnustl_static' to module 'ObjectRecognition'
    Android NDK: WARNING:E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk:ObjectRecognition: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java

    Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
    Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
    Android NDK:     current module
    Android NDK: [armeabi] Modules to build: ObjectRecognition
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    make: *** [E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ObjectRecognition] Error 1

    E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition>ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK
    _APPLICATION_MK=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT
    =E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\build\intermediates
    \ndkBuild\debug\lib clean NDK_LOG=1
    Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: 'E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//..'
    Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
    Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: windows
    Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: windows
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
    Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to windows
    Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
    Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe -n
    Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/cmp.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe
    Android NDK: Host 'awk' test returned: Pass
    Android NDK: Found platform root directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms
    Android NDK: Found supported platforms: android-12 android-13 android-14 android-15 android-16 android-17 android-18 android-19 android-21 android-22 android-23 android-2
    4 android-9
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-12 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-12/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-13 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-13/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-14 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-15 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-15/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-16 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-17 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-17/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-18 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-18/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-19 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-x86
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-21 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-22 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-22/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-23 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-24 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm64
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-mips64
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-x86
    Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-x86_64
    Android NDK: PLATFORM android-9 supports: arm mips x86
    Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-arm
    Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-mips
    Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-x86
    Android NDK: Found stable platform levels: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 9
    Android NDK: Found max platform level: 24
    Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following target architectures and ABIS:
    Android NDK:    arm: armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    arm64: arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    mips: mips
    Android NDK:    mips64: mips64
    Android NDK:    x86: x86
    Android NDK:    x86_64: x86_64
    Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following toolchains and target ABIs:
    Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-4.9:  arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-clang:  arm64-v8a
    Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.9:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
    Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-4.9:  mips64
    Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-clang:  mips64
    Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.9:  mips
    Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang:  mips
    Android NDK:    x86-4.9:  x86
    Android NDK:    x86-clang:  x86
    Android NDK:    x86_64-4.9:  x86_64
    Android NDK:    x86_64-clang:  x86_64
    Android NDK: Make no attempt to look for NDK_PROJECT_PATH.
    Android NDK: Ouput path for intermediate files: E:/Android/Aditya/poc/ObjectRecognition/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
    Android NDK: Ouput path for generated library files: E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib
    Android NDK: Parsing E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk
    Android NDK:   APP_PIE is
    Android NDK:   Enabling -fPIE
    Android NDK:   Using build script E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
    Android NDK: Application 'local' is not debuggable
    Android NDK: Selecting release optimization mode (app is not debuggable)
    Android NDK: Adding import directory: E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources
    Android NDK: Building application 'local' for ABI 'armeabi'
    Android NDK:   Enabling -fPIE for TARGET_PLATFORM android-19
    Android NDK: Using target toolchain 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang' for 'armeabi' ABI (through NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)
    Android NDK: Looking for imported module with tag 'cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++'
    Android NDK:   Probing E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk
    Android NDK:     Found in E:/Android/AndroidSDK/SDK/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++
    Android NDK: Module 'ObjectRecognition' has C++ sources
    Android NDK: Add dependency 'gnustl_static' to module 'ObjectRecognition'
    Android NDK: WARNING:E:\Android\Aditya\poc\ObjectRecognition\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk:ObjectRecognition: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java

    Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
    Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
    Android NDK:     current module
    Android NDK: [armeabi] Modules to build: ObjectRecognition
    'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    make: *** [clean-ObjectRecognition-armeabi] Error 1
```

C:\users\R is not the user I haved logged in with. My username is R&D -2.

Comment: It looks like there's a space in your user name, and that the tools are trying to execute something within your user directory. It looks like both the NDK and your source are not in your user directory, so without more logs it's hard to say what the problem is. Could you add `arguments "V=1"` to your `ndkBuild` section? That will enable verbose output from ndk-build.

Comment: Thank you @DanAlbert for the reply. I did a build with the arguments "V=1" as you suggested but I got the same log as the output. I have added NDK_LOG=1 output in the edit

Comment: "My username is R&D". Hmm. That would explain why our "you have a space in your directory" checks haven't fired. I don't think we check all of the shell special characters that can mess with things. I'm still not sure why it's looking in your user directory anyway. The log output is... interesting. Could you try making a minimal test case? If this is still failing in the most basic case, could you file a bug at https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/new and I'll take a closer look?